# What is the point of class-level type hints in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, type-hinting

I'm trying to understand the point of class-type hints. I know that we can use type hints in the `__init__` method of a class, like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x
```

However, I came across another way of defining type hints at the class level, as shown in the following example:

```
class Bar:
    x : int
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x
```

What is the purpose of using class-level type hints like this? Do they provide any additional benefits or information compared to using type hints only in the `__init__` method?

Comment: to tell the type of class variables

Comment: The type hints in the `__init__` method are for the _parameters_, which isn't the same thing as typing the _attributes_. In your second example a type checker can validate that `self.x = x` is correct.

Comment: @sahasrara62 no, those type hints are for instance not class attributes https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations

Comment: `Bar.x` and `my_bar.x` where `my_bar = Bar(1)` are different things though right?

Comment: @jonrsharpe didn't knew this, thanks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you please elaborate on validating the type? Because when I do `Bar("cat")` I don't get any errors on either `Foo` or `Bar`.

Comment: It allows _a type checker_ to validate the assignment. See the first note in https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html. And your example would be the parameter type, which is the same in both.

Comment: @JonSG Oh I didn't know about that! I've never used such a thing. Now I understand the difference!

Comment: my_bar.x will overwrite the class variable x, Bar.x will give default value if it is initialised ie x: int = 1, something, otherwise it throw error  and not same

Comment: @Peyman type hints are *hints*, they are not enforced at runtime

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga little confusing to understand, need to go deep, but quite interesting feature. Thanks for telling this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *"class-level type hints"*, despite appearing where you'd normally see class attributes, explicitly specify the expected types of *instance* attributes (except where `ClassVar` is used). As explained in [PEP-526](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations):

> #### Class and instance variable annotations
>
> Type annotations can also be used to annotate class and instance
> variables in class bodies and methods. In particular, the value-less
> notation `a: int` allows one to annotate instance variables that
> should be initialized in `__init__` or `__new__`. The proposed syntax
> is as follows:
>
> ```
> class BasicStarship:
>     captain: str = 'Picard'               # instance variable with default
>     damage: int                           # instance variable without default
>     stats: ClassVar[Dict[str, int]] = {}  # class variable
> ```
>
> Here `ClassVar` is a special class defined by the typing module that
> indicates to the static type checker that this variable should not be
> set on instances.

---

Why would you use them?

In your first example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x
```

the *parameter* to `__init__` has a type hint, preventing e.g. `Foo(123)`, but the type of the *attribute* `Foo("bar").x` has to be **inferred** from the assignment `self.x = x` in `__init__`.

By contrast, in your second example:

```
class Bar:
    x : int
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x
```

you have an explicit definition of the type of `self.x`, so the assignment can actually be validated by e.g. MyPy.

---

Why is that useful?

Giving the type system more information allows it to help you more precisely. If, for example, you subsequently *changed* the parameter type:

```
class Bar:
    x: int
    def __init__(self, x: str):
                        # ^~~
        self.x = x
```

rather than getting errors all over your codebase where `some_bar.x` is *accessed*, assuming it's an `int` (as you would in the case that the attribute's type was inferred), you'd get **one error** pointing you straight to where it's *assigned* and know exactly where to fix it:

```
class Bar:
    x: int
    def __init__(self, x: str):
        self.x = int(x)
```

---

As always, though, remember (per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)):

> **Note** The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type
> checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.

Python itself won't error on this, you need tools like MyPy to get the most use out of the annotations.